# An alternative to using standard marker for 2D color plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

At the moment I have a somewhat crude python program that I would like to modify to do the following:

Read in three columns of data from a single file (X,Y,C) which are then plotted as a 2D X,Y scatter plot with the C value representing the color map value.  Each X,Y point represents the center of a square box of fixed size which will be colored based on the C value. The X,Y coordinates are such that there won't be any overlapping boxes - although there will be gaps where there are no coordinates.  The size of the box will be fixed for each input file (but can vary from one file to the next) and the program is supposed to color in each square box depending on the C value. For instance, the desired plot for one particular input file might have 5,000 X,Y coordinates somewhere in the range X from 1000 to 6000 and Y from 2000 to 7000, with the desired box size being 40, and the color range going from 1 to 1700.

Currently the program is a hack based on using the standard marker to colour each box, so essentially the marker represents the size of the box. It works ok but requires selecting the correct marker size and also adjusting the size of the plot to ensure that boxes (i.e. the markers) fit without gap or overlap. This adjustment is specific to each input file - i.e. the X,Y range and the box size (based on minimum distance between points). So I am thinking how to automate this so that the program can read in any file (regardless of box size) and color in each box without requiring a lot of user input (perhaps box size will need to be entered somewhere) - so I guess not using the standard marker.

Current code:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10.0, 10.5)) 
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = '#55AAFF' # background color 
plt.scatter(X, Y, c=colrsabove, s=marker_size, marker='s', alpha=0.8, cmap='YlOrRd')
```

Comment: Can you show us what code you have so far?

Comment: `plt.figure(figsize=(10.0, 10.5))  
plt.rcParams['axes.facecolor'] = '#55AAFF'  # background color
plt.scatter(X, Y, c=colrsabove, s=marker_size, marker='s', alpha=0.8,
            cmap='YlOrRd')`

Comment: So for a particular X,Y range, and a particular box size (here 40), then it turns out that a marker size of 's' will be approximately the right size. But if I read in another file, then the X,Y ranges can change, so can the box size, and the marker then would not be the correct size...possibly adjusting the figure size and marker could get a reasonable fit..

Comment: All of this sounds a lot like your data lies on a grid and it would hence be better plotting your data as image.

Comment: Could be..can you provide more details on this? I think in a nutshell what is needed is for the program to directly color in a square zone centered on each X,Y coordinate point. So for instance I can tell the program that the box is 40 by 40 units and then it can color that in directly - without the hack of using a marker. Anyway, I will google plotting as an image ... thanks for the tip..